# ArrayListの変数をランダムに出力したい

Tags: java

ArrayListについて質問です。
現在、ArrayListの変数、「languages」を作り、その値をランダムに出力しようとしています。
しかし、出力する際、`error: array required, but ArrayList<String> found`と出てきてしまいます。
後に変数を追加する可能性も含めて、配列ではなくArrayListを使って出力したいです。

**現状のコード:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
public class Main{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        
        Random random = new Random();
        ArrayList<String> languages = new ArrayList<>();
        languages.add("Java");
        languages.add("Ruby");
        languages.add("PHP");
        languages.add("Swift");
        languages.add("Python");
        
        String language = languages[random.nextInt(5)];
        System.out.println(language);
        
    }
}
```

初歩的な質問ですいません。
解決策がわかる方、教えてくれると嬉しいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayList` で要素の順番を指定して取得するには [`get()` メソッド](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)) を利用します。

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
public class Main{
    public static void main (String[] args){

        Random random = new Random();
        ArrayList<String> languages = new ArrayList<>();
        languages.add("Java");
        languages.add("Ruby");
        languages.add("PHP");
        languages.add("Swift");
        languages.add("Python");

        String language = languages.get(random.nextInt(5));
        System.out.println(language);

    }
}
```